# Is Cotoneaster an appropriate plant to fill an empty space along my fence?

Tags: plant-recommendations, hedge, privacy-plants

I have 8ft Leylandii along the outside of most of my west and north facing fences, but there are some gaps on the north side, so I have been using a range of climbing plants inside the fence to provide some privacy, but after seeing some lovely dense cotoneaster covered walls and fences I was wondering whether I should plant them inside the fence at these points.

I live in central Scotland, on clay soil. The fence is a common type - diagonal wood planks with gaps.

Comment: I don't know how big your gaps are, but Leylandii is notorious for crowding other plants out - so you might have problems starting the cotoneaster if the gaps are medium/small.

Comment: @winwaed - thanks - have updated question to say cotoneaster **inside** the fence. Leylandii outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have one cotoneaster growing in clay and it is a star performer.  The glossy green leaves and bright red berries are a real treat for the eye. The right species can be trained up a fence to 4 or 5' tall and tolerates pruning well

I do agree with Michael Dirr's assessment that the way the branches grow makes it a real catchall for leaves and other debris.
If there is anything blowing around your garden in the wind it will end up in the cotoneaster. Otherwise, thumbs up.

As a note to the wise, some cotoneaster species have escaped cultivation in Europe and are now  considered to be an invasive weed. Investigate the species offered with care.